# How to generate a random ID for body tag upon page load using a set array of IDs

Tags: jquery, html, random

Here's my issue:

I have a very simple html website teaser right now with a large background image (www.iambold.org).

The background image is set up on the body tag, and so is the background color. What I need is for the body tag to be randomly assigned a different ID whenever the page is loaded.

The reason for this is that each separate ID will have a different background image and different background color associated with it.

The last part is that I need the generator to only select between the IDs that I have set in the css file.

Here's the CSS for the body backgrounds:

```
body {font-family:'Lato',verdana,arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:22px; }
body#body_1 {background:#fff url(../images/bg_splash.jpg) center -15px repeat-x;}
body#body_2 {background:#353932 url(../images/bg_splash2.jpg) center -15px repeat-x;}
```

I am familiar with jquery, and can hack codes well enough to do what I need, but I am not good enough to write my own code for these types of things.

Comment: Is there a min or max number for your random values? Have you looked at [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) at the Mozilla Developer Network? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: The max number will be however many backgrounds I make for it. So it'll change. I haven't tried anything yet. I've just been trawling the internet to see if anyone has asked this question before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Store the possible IDs in a list (array).
2. Generate a random integer using `Math.random()` and `Math.floor()`.
3. Pick the element from the list.
4. Set the `id` attribute to the element's value.

Example (no jQuery needed for this simple script):

```
$(function(){ //<-- That's jQuery, because `document.body` does not exist
              // in the head of the document.
    var styleIds = ["body1", "body2"];
    document.body.id = styleIds[ Math.floor(Math.random()*styleIds.length) ];
});
```

The `Math.random()` method returns a random number satisfying `0 <= x < 1`. `Math.floor` floors the number. With a list size of 2, the possible numbers are: 0 and 1, which is what we want, because indexes of arrays are zero-based.

Comment: @jkilp You can [mark the answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110461/169101) by clicking at the Green tick (at the left side). If the answer is uber-awesome, you can also upvote the answer, on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids = ['body_1', 'body_2', 'body_3'];
$(function () {
    $('body').attr('id', ids[Math.floor(Math.random()*ids.length)])
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FAS6R/)

if you keep you css declarations constant, just put this at the bottom of you page

```
    <script> document.body.id = "body_" + Math.floor(Math.random()*[NUMBER_OF_DECLARATIONS]); </script>
</body>
```

Comment: pls don't use jQuery for this D:

Answer (score 0):

I would use simple classes instead of ID selectors in your CSS.  So define several classes in CSS then use the following snippet to assign a random class.

```
var classes = [ "classBg1", "classBg2", "classBg3" ];

$.ready( function() {
    var nextClass = classes[ Math.round( classes.length * Math.random() ) ];
    $('body').addClass( nextClass );
});
```

Comment: pls don't use jQuery for this D:

Comment: The user said they were using and familiar with jQuery.  Using jQuery for this is up to them.  Not me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an array with valid ids and then grab a random element from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.random()` to generate a random no. between 0 and 1. Then you can `Math.floor()` to take the nearest no. and then assign this to your body tags and have them pick one based on what is generated by `Math.random()` functions

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a class and you should use simple DOM calls instead of jQuery.  That being said:

```
var classList = ["v1","v2","v3","v4"];
document.body.className = classList[Math.round(Math.random()*4)];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, determine the highest tag you can use, assuming a base of `#body_1`

```
var iMax = $("style:contains('#body_')").length;
```

Then, set a random one to the body tag:

```
$('body').attr('id','body_' + (Math.floor(iMax)+1));
```

That should do it.