# Random body background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, background, document-body

I've tried several tutorial on the web and none seems to work properly. What I'm trying to do is quite simple I think:

I have 9 different .jpg images that I need to randomly show up on page load - to be  background. This should be fairly simple right?

Thanks,

EDIT (Sorry, forgot to attach the code - found in the web):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    bgImageTotal=9;

    randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random()*(bgImageTotal-1))+1;

    imgPath=('../img/bg/'+randomNumber+'.jpg');

    $('body').css('background-image', ('url("'+imgPath+'")'));

});
```

Comment: It is generally preferred if you post some code which you have tried to use which will not work rather than just ask people to write it for you.

Comment: True, sorry.. forgot to attach the code.

Comment: Yeah, it'd all depend on what language you're using as to how you'd do it.

Comment: Related: [How to generate a random ID for body tag upon page load using a set array of IDs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673090/how-to-generate-a-random-id-for-body-tag-upon-page-load-using-a-set-array-of-ids)

Comment: The posted code assumes that your images are stored in a folder named `img` which is at the same level as the folder your html is in, inside of a subfolder named `bg`.  It also assumes that your images are named `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` etc.  Is this all true?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check out this tutorial: http://briancray.com/2009/12/28/simple-image-randomizer-jquery/

First create an array of images:

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg'];
```

Then, set a random image as the background image:

```
$('body').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() *      images.length)] + ')'});
```

That should work no problem.

Comment: What should I call my function? 
I'm not used to javascript, thanks.

Comment: you shouldn't need to call a function, just put it inside of the jQuery $(document).ready(function() {} tag.

Comment: Yes it works! I had a problem with the script link to jQuery. I wasn't linking the library in first place. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If you can, I'd very much appreciate an accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery: `$("body").css("background-image", "url(" + Math.floor(Math.random()*9) + ".jpg)");`

This is assuming, that your images are named 0.jpg until 8.jpg and are in the same directory as your page.